# VS 2010 SP1 32-bit Remote Debugging Monitor under Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, windows-10, visual-studio-debugging

I need to work on an out-of-browser Silverlight application, provided as a VS 2010 project.
I am on a Windows 10, 64-bit machine, with a Silverlight 5 installation. I have successfully installed Visual Studio 2010 SP1, 32-bit, on this computer and been running SL out-of-browser projects with it. Now, I want to execute the project in debug mode from VS 2010 (launch from green arrow), but I get a textbox error message saying that the 32-bit version of the Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) cannot be used to debug 64-bit processes or 64-bit dumps.

Since I have installed on my Windows 10 computer several VS versions, including the 2017 one, I tried to "fool" the VS 2010 debugger by copying in the right folder debug correspondents from the 2017 folder, both 32 and 64 bit; but that didn't work.

I have also asked a question on the MSDN VS Forum, in the "Debug" section, but got no answer.

Please note that the build executes OK, that I can install the binary output as an SL application and that it runs perfectly.

My question is: how can I make working the **debug** mode for my Silverlight application in VS 2010 SP under these circumstances?

Comment: To debug 64-bit applications locally, Visual Studio uses a 64-bit worker process (msvsmon.exe) to perform the low-level operations that cannot be done inside of the 32-bit Visual Studio process, do you install the 64 bit remote debugging tool?.https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=475

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT: In the installation folder of my VS 2010 SP1 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64 - I have msvsmon.exe. I also have C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x86\msvsmon.exe. How a VS 2010 instance selects one or another I ignore. What should I check/do next? Thanks

Comment: Remote debugging means that you want to debug the specific app in remote machine, if so , what is your another Windows Environment? You have to setup two machines Environment firstly. Maybe these documents are helpful:https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146838/Remote-debugging-with-Visual-Studio and http://www.technoideas.com/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-with-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: I don't want to debug from a remote computer, just on the same machine, as I mentioned on my initial posting. Clicking on the green arrow should trigger the out-of-browser Silverlight project step-by-step execution. But doing that today gives me that error, where 'remote debugging' is mentined by the system. The 'remote debugger' is not my need, it is just inside the error message.

Comment: Whether all projects have the same issue? For example, the Silverlight 4 project or a simple C# Console app. See: https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/MSDNSweden/Debugging-Silverlight-4-Out-Of-Browser-applications-in-Visual-Studio-2010, we have to make sure that whether it is related to the debugger tool or the project itself firstly. I will try to setup the Environment and test it in my side later.

Comment: I started the post with the error message I've got, which might be misleading. For short, the issue is: how to run in debug mode a Silverlight out-of-browser project using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 under Windows 10? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed VS2010(also installed the SP1 for it) in my windows 10, to create the SL5 app, I install the SL 5 SDK, and then test it like the video:

https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/MSDNSweden/Debugging-Silverlight-4-Out-Of-Browser-applications-in-Visual-Studio-2010

I use the same steps for the Silverlight 5 app in my side, it works well.

Could you debug or run your app before using your VS2010 in your windows 10? Not run the SL 5 app, how about a simple SL 4 app? Please also deactivated the firewall and antivirus in your windows. View the result again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works perfect, your answer synthesizes how it should be done! The firewall and antivirus should not be touched, also both SL 4.0 and 5.0 do the job. The error message I've got is really aside of the road, but it's true Silverlight is not supported anymore by MSFT. The problem I had was simply related to a .NET version not installed on my Windows 10 machine (hm, what about backward compatibility ?...). Thanks again